# jQuery off not working as I expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Resolved!! see the end of the question for the result that I used

I am trying to write a function that can handle my apps paging by routes.

I have a function route() that is called with argument being the route(page) to move to.

route is an object that defines a model that it uses that handles its logic.
This model contains 3 functions
  indexAction
    - This renders my view and appends it to my page.
  bindEvents
    - This is where I have placed all of my click events
  shutDown
    - This is instructions to run when moving to a new page

The router function first runs shutdown on the current page, here I have the $(selector).off() and $(selector).remove()

it then runs the enidexAction and bindEvents function.

My issue now is when I return to this page, all my click functions are running twice, then three times etc... its as if the off() never actually unbind from the anchor.

here is an example of one of my models

```
var NewPageModel = (function() {
var instance;
var modal = 'null';
function createInstance() {
    var object = {
        indexAction: indexAction,
        shutDown: shutDown,
        bindEvents: bindEvents
    };
    return object;
}

function indexAction (data, callback){
    var partials = {};
    ViewManager.render('pageName',{context:data}, partials,function(html){
        ViewManager.appendUnique('#xxx',html,'uniqueID');
        callback();
    });
}

/**
 * Remove modal
 */
function shutDown(){
    this.modal.off();
    this.modal.remove();
}

function bindEvents() {
    if(this.modal!='null'){
        return;
    }
    this.modal = $(PagerManager.pages.newGroup.id);

    this.modal.on('click','div.close', function () {
        shutDown();
    });

    this.modal.on('click', 'button.cancel', function () {
       shutDown();
    });

    this.modal.on('click', 'button.submit', function () {
       //code that submits form information
    });
}

return {
    getInstance: function () {
        if (!this.instance) {
            this.instance = createInstance();
        }
        return this.instance;
    }
};
})();
```

EDIT!!
So I am still learning about the importance of scopes and how they can be applied to functions
Here is the working code
    var NewPageModel = (function() {
    var instance;
    var modal;
    function createInstance() {
        var object = {
            indexAction: indexAction,
            shutDown: shutDown,
            bindEvents: bindEvents
        };
        return object;
    }

```
function indexAction (data, callback){
    var partials = {};
    ViewManager.render('pageName',{context:data}, partials,function(html){
        ViewManager.appendUnique('#xxx',html,'uniqueID');
        callback();
    });
}

/**
 * Remove modal
 */
function shutDown(){
    this.modal.off();
    this.modal.remove();
    this.modal = null;
}

function bindEvents() {
    //This is confused logic, if I use off() in shutdown, I don't need to do this as I need to bind all the events again. hence in shutdown modal=null;
    if(!this.modal){
        return;
    }
    this.modal = $('#modal');

    this.modal.on('click','div.close', function () {
        shutDown().apply(this);
    }).bind(this);;

    this.modal.on('click', 'button.cancel', function () {
       shutDown().apply(this);
    }).bind(this);;

    this.modal.on('click', 'button.submit', function () {
       //here I only use the apply(this) if I use another internal function 
       //code that submits form information
    }).bind(this);;
}

return {
    getInstance: function () {
        if (!this.instance) {
            this.instance = createInstance();
        }
        return this.instance;
    }
};
})();
```

Comment: `if(this.modal!='null'){` really dude?

Comment: @AlienWebguy please offer a suggestion of how better to asses this. Im not a javascript developer and am trying...

Comment: JavaScript aside, `null` exists for a reason in programming

Comment: ok granted it should not be defined as a string but rather NULL as in NULL Object or NULL reference.
However, my issue here is the multiple binding. I don't understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Beyerz: Your `var modal = 'null'` does not create a property on an object. It creates a local variable that is shard by all the functions inside the IIFE. The value of `this` in a function is dynamic, and defined at the time of the call. Do you intend `this` to refer to the instance and for `this.modal` to refer to a property on the instance? If so, then put a `modal: null` property in your `createInstance()` and change the condition to `if(this.modal != null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of keeping your syntax and just fixing the bug,

`if(this.modal!='null'){` should be `if(modal!='null'){`

Because `this.modal` will be `undefined` at that condition and will just return.

In the spirit of fixing your code, you need to keep a reference to `this` or it will default to `window` in the browser.

```
var modal;
function createInstance() {
    var object = {
        modal : modal,
        shutDown: shutDown,
        bindEvents: bindEvents
    };
    return object;
}

function bindEvents() {
    if(this.modal){
        return;
    }

   // ..... //
    this.modal.on('click','div.close', function () {
        shutDown.apply(this);
    }.bind(this));

   // ..... //
}
```

Working demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/uyovgdj3/

Comment: As model is a property initialized on the function/object, surely it does require the reference to `this.modal`? I see your JSFiddle is correct for that check (`if (this.modal)`)

Comment: so if I understand correctly I only need to bind the scope to a function that needs the scope, in this instance the shutdown function. Or do I need to also bind the scope to .on('click'... type events like for my submit button that does not call the shutdown function?

Comment: I chose to go with this solution as it is fairly easy to understand the relationship of the scope as well as it fits my situation perfectly. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

You are losing your `this` in the event handler functions (`this` will be the element clicked) so the `shutDown` is not getting the correct `this`:

```
this.modal.on('click','div.close', function () {
    shutDown();
});
```

should be:

```
var self = this;
this.modal.on('click', 'button.cancel', function () {
   self.shutDown();
});
```

e.g.

```
function bindEvents() {
    var self = this;
    if(this.modal!='null'){           /// <<<< !!!!!! WTF
        return;
    }
    this.modal = $(PagerManager.pages.newGroup.id);

    this.modal.on('click','div.close', function () {
        self.shutDown();
    });

    this.modal.on('click', 'button.cancel', function () {
       self.shutDown();
    });

    this.modal.on('click', 'button.submit', function () {
       //code that submits form information
    });
}
```

**Note:** I am ignoring the string comparison to `null` for now as I have no clue what you are doing there :)

As pointed out in comment by `@Gurami Dagundaridze` you can also retain the correct `this` using `bind` (I think the syntax goes like this):

```
    this.modal.on('click', 'button.cancel', shutDown.bind(this));
```

Comment: isnt it better to use bind()?

Comment: @True, but it doesn't explain his multiple binding, which is what he's asking about. But either way, the better solution to that problem would be to do `this.modal.on("click", "div.close", shutDown);` and then change `shutDown` to do `$(this).off().remove()`.

Comment: @squint: If his `shutDown` is not called with a correct `this`, then it will not disconnect the handlers (which would explain the multiples).

Comment: i mean shutDown.bind(this); javascript native function not jquerys bind

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Right, but the only need for the correct `this` in his function is to get back to the `modal` element. And if he does `this.modal.on("click" "div.close", shutDown)`, then `this` in `shutDown` will be a direct reference to the `modal` element, so all that extra code isn't needed.

Comment: @squint: Will not the `this` be the element clicked in a delegated handler? (ie. `div.close`). I think you are thinking of a non-delegated handler (which would pass modal as the `this`)

Comment: ah... you're right. I totally missed the event delegation. By "delegated" I thought you meant the anonymous function being a delegate for the `shutDown()` function.

Comment: I would like to be able to call the shutdown function from the interface, how then do I call it seeings I cant use self.shutdown?